# Connect to network device in java

Tags: java, networking, ping

I need to connect to a hardware device which is in LAN, and we need to ping that device through some hex code and the device is sending some response to the ping command. How do I read that response?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :-). We'd like to help, but your question is a bit vague. Please read [ask]. As to your question: **What have you tried so far?**

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to look up networking code, specifically, sockets. Although it takes a bit of extra learning, sockets are best handle using a few threads, unless you are willing to have your application wait for the response.

I would give more info, but I doubt you will even notice this, if you do I can add some more info for you.